# Setting the right timezone, server and PHP

Tags: php, linux, laravel, time

I need to set the right timezone.
But I don't understand if there is any difference between the PHP timezone (`date_default_timezone_set()`) and the Linux setting.

Suppose I run a new AWS instance from N.Virginia. The default timezone of that server should be `UTC-05:00`

Does this mean that I have to set `UTC-05:00` inside my PHP ini config?

If I set UTC in the php.ini on a N. Virginia server does this will mean that php will convert automatically the date from `UTC-05:00` (time of the server) to `UTC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in `Laravel`, you can set your timezone from `env.php` file or directly from `config\app.php` for example, in `config\app.php` file you'll find something like this:

```
'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE') ?: 'UTC',
```

In this case, if you have an `env.php` environment file, then it'll look for `APP_TIMEZONE` which could be something like following:

```
APP_TIMEZONE=Asia/Dhaka
```

If you don't have an `env.php` file then you may replace the `UTC` part from `'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE') ?: 'UTC'` in the `config\app.php` file directly. You may find all timezones from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php), look for yours.

Comment: I accepted your answer, even tho I was asking something different: e.g. if the server has an utc-5 time, can I safely set UTC in laravel ? Does php converts the time automatically based on the -5 difference?

Comment: Yes, that's the same as `PHP`s `date_default_timezone_set `.